# XSLT - How to select XML Attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, apache-fop

I've got xml file:

```
<root>
<host>
<address addr="192.168.0.1" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<ports>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="10"></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="20"></port>
</ports>
</host>
<host>
<address addr="192.168.0.2" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<ports>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="30"></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="40"></port>
</ports>
</host>
<root>
```

I want get  results like this:

```
192.168.0.1 10,20
192.168.0.2 30,40
```

I’m using for-each (for first column):

```
<xsl:for-each select="root/host">
<xsl:value-of select="address/@addr"/></fo:block>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But second column is a problem.. I get wrong results:

```
192.168.0.1 10,20,30,40
192.168.0.2 10,20,30,40
```

Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:for-each select="root/host">
<xsl:value-of select="address/@addr"/>
<xsl:for-each select="ports/port">
<xsl:value-of select="@portid"/>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

you can try above on some sample xslt editor like
http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog_ex3

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate again through all the child 'port' elements. The following should work:

```
<xsl:for-each select="root/host">
   <xsl:value-of select="address/@addr" />
   <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
   <xsl:for-each select="ports/port">
      <xsl:value-of select="@portid" />
      <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">,</xsl:if>
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```